# mass-assign protected attributes in Rail 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got the error message WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for
There is a method "Strong parameter can solve the problem" but  failed
I don't want to do `attr_accessible :title, :description` in every Model,
I'd rather use the Strong parameter
I use the 'group_params' method in the code , to edit/new model
Here my code https://gist.github.com/poc7667/5993437#file-group_controller

And below are my gem list
I use some gems may have hidden problems ?

devise 
simple_form

Thanks you all in advance ^_^

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.0.0)
  * actionpack (4.0.0)
  * activemodel (4.0.0)
  * activerecord (4.0.0)
  * activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
  * activesupport (4.0.0)
  * arel (4.0.0)
  * atomic (1.1.10)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1)
  * builder (3.1.4)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.0)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
  * devise (3.0.0.rc)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.4)
  * jbuilder (1.4.2)
  * jquery-rails (3.0.4)
  * json (1.8.0)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * mime-types (1.23)
  * minitest (4.7.5)
  * multi_json (1.7.7)
  * orm_adapter (0.4.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * protected_attributes (1.0.2)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.0.0)
  * railties (4.0.0)
  * rake (10.1.0)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * sass (3.2.9)
  * sass-rails (4.0.0)
  * sdoc (0.3.20)
  * simple_form (3.0.0.rc)
  * sprockets (2.10.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.7)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * thread_safe (0.1.0)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * treetop (1.4.14)
  * turbolinks (1.3.0)
  * tzinfo (0.3.37)
  * uglifier (2.1.2)
  * warden (1.2.2)
```

Comment: remove the gem `protected_attributes`from your `Gemfile`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the gem

`protected_attributes (1.0.2)` [(Github)](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes)

Which adds the old attr_accessible mass-assignment protection to your models.