# Strong params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment

I removed mass assignment vulnerability of the below line :

```
friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
friend.update_attributes(params[:name])
```

by rewriting it as :

```
friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
friend.update_attributes(params.permit(:name))
```

But this gave me this error :

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Friend: name):
Unpermitted parameters: id
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

`Edit :`

I added `attr_accessible :status_id` and `params.permit(:id, :name)` and the error got removed. But is adding `attr_accessible` the right way to do it as we write strong params to remove this line, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessible` in your model?

Comment: Show `params.inspect`. Be sure you are checking right part of code - maybe you edit update method, but triggering a create method.

Comment: `params.permit(:name, :id)`

Comment: I have removed `attr_accessible` from my model and doing `params.permit(:name, :id)` doesn't work

Comment: One quick way to fix this issue is to not send `id` from frontend at all as you have mentioned here "`params = {"name"=>"John", "id"=>"15"}`". because anyway you are not saving it to database

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code as `friend.update_attributes(params.permit(:name, :id))`
to allow that parameter.

Comment: Didn't work. Getting this `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Friend: id, name)`

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
friend.update_attributes(params.require(:friend).permit(:name))
```

or put this into an private method

```
private
def object_params
  params.require(:friend).permit(:name)
end
```

and then call via

```
friend.update_attributes object_params
```

edit:
i'm assuming that your params look like

```
{friend:{name:'xxxxx'},id:xx}
```

Comment: I can't do this as I get the params as named `params` from the front end.

Comment: look again at the example. i just put the params into an private controller method. :). you can use allready this `friend.update_attributes(params.require(:friend).permit(:name))`

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, my params look like : `params = {"name"=>"John", "id"=>"15"}`

Comment: oh ok. thank you. your model becomes an hash with name and id, and you just allow name. so the error is correct, because you dont want to put the id into the update_attribute. try `params.slice(:name).permit(:name)` for the update

Comment: Do I still need to use `attr_accessible :name` because it doesn't work without this line

Comment: no. its just because of passing parameters which contains field which are allowed. you try my last comment?

Comment: Yeah, even your last comment didn't fix the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80698/discussion-between-rob-and-hellboy).

Comment: theres another hint (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637253/mass-assign-protected-attributes-in-rail-4) dont forget to bundle after this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the attr_accessible in model, Rails 4 uses the strong parameter.

Try this code .

```
friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
friend.update_attributes(friend_params)

private

  def friend_params    
    params.require(:friend).permit!    
  end
```

Comment: As I told, I am getting my params as `params`, not as `friend `

Comment: As you are getting the params of friend so you need to require the friend to permit the params of fiend model. Does my code work?